# Is there any better way to implement PetersonFilter lock in C++

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, locks

My Implementation is a simple bookish implementation of Peterson filter lock.
I have very basic knowledge of C++. It would be very helpful if someone suggests, hack way to implement in C++.

```
class PetersonsFilterLock {
private:
  volatile size_t no_of_threads;
  volatile size_t *level;
  volatile size_t *victim;

public:
  PetersonsFilterLock(size_t num_threads);
  void lock(size_t tid);
  void unlock(size_t tid);
};

PetersonsFilterLock::PetersonsFilterLock(size_t num_threads) {
  no_of_threads = num_threads;
  level = new size_t[no_of_threads];
  victim = new size_t[no_of_threads];
  for(size_t i=0; i<no_of_threads; i++){
    level[i] = 0;
  }
}

void PetersonsFilterLock::lock(size_t tid) {
  for(size_t i=1; i<no_of_threads; i++){
    level[tid] = i;
    victim[i] = tid;
    for(size_t k=0; k<no_of_threads; k++){
        while( k!=tid && level[k] >=i && victim[i] == tid) {}
    }
  }
}

void PetersonsFilterLock::unlock(size_t tid) {
  level[tid] = 0;
}
```

THanks

Comment: In c++11 you must use `atomics`, and there is no portable way before c++11. `volatile` won't help you at all.

Comment: My code is working with volatile. Can you please explain why to use atomic in place of volatile.

Comment: `Volatile` in C++ prevents only compiler optimizations and reordering. It doesn't guaranty atomicity nor ordering. It could work on CPU with strong memory model (such as x86), but will fail of CPU with weak memory model (such as Power or ARM).